# Some xbindkeys bindings don't work via .xprofile, requires manual process restart

Tags: linux, x11, key-bindings, keymapping

All of my `.xbindkeysrc` bindings work when I explicity run `xbindkeys`; however, when I put the same command in my `.xprofile` to be called by my display manager, LightDM, certain bindings fail. The bindings that fail to work on start-up use the `playerctl` command. All of my other bindings work (the others call `pactl ...`).

```
# Next song
 "playerctl --player spotify next"
    Mod2 + F8
```

If I kill the broken `xbindkeys` process that began on startup and re-run `xbindkeys`, all of the bindings work.

Any suggestions? Maybe, where could I run `xbindkeys` at a later point in the start-up process?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `playerctl` isn't in your *system* path. Depending on how `xbindkeys` is started its path may only be something like:

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
```

As a result it won't find the command and nothing happens when you press the key combination in question.

On Debian `xbindkeys` is started by the `/usr/bin/xbindkeys_autostart` script. For debugging it may help to temporarily modify that script a little, for example as follows:

```
@@ -22,6 +22,11 @@

     # Run $PROG - if it has been configured
     if [ -n "${CONF}" ]; then
-        $PROG -f $CONF
+        echo ===== >> /tmp/xbk.txt
+        date >> /tmp/xbk.txt
+        cat $CONF >> /tmp/xbk.txt
+        env >> /tmp/xbk.txt
+        echo ----- >> /tmp/xbk.txt
+        $PROG -f $CONF -v 2>&1 >> /tmp/xbk.txt
     fi
 fi
```

(If you modify that script keep in mind that output to the log file is buffered, so you may have to create enough output by hitting your key bindings for the system to flush the file, or use something like `unbuffer`.)